# Completion callback not executing on set method in firebase 3.0.2

Tags: node.js, firebase

In my **Nodejs** application, I am trying to set some data to my firebase location called "callback" using **firebase 3.0.2** module like below.

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp({
      serviceAccount: "path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json",
      databaseURL: "<My firebase url>"
});

var db = firebase.database();
var callbackref = db.ref("callback");

console.log("Before Call");

callbackref.set("Some data", function (error) {
   console.log("Callback Executed");
});

console.log("After Call");
```

After executing above code I can see messages in my console as below

```
"Before Call"
"After Call"
```

And I can see the updated data in my firebase console to my "callback" location but the only problem here is I never get "Callback Executed" message in my console.

My **Nodejs version is 5.5.0**
Operation System is **Windows 10**.

My Problem is **Completion callback never executed**. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hello Ashok, there's not enough here to reproduce your error. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include as much detail as possible.

Comment: @Kato edited my question. Issue is completion callback never executed but I can see updated data in Firebase console.

Comment: The code you have here worked for me. The "Callback executed" log happens after the other two, of course, because it's asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug fixed in 3.0.3 which would cause your code to run, but the authentication to silently fail if given an invalid service account without the proper permissions. Try upgrading to version 3.0.3 and also try turning on debugging via `firebase.database.enableLogging(true)`. I have a feeling you will need to re-generate your service account JSON file via the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app).

Comment: I have the same issue with `update()` method on firebase 3.14.0.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Promise returned by `set` -

```
var usersRef = ref.child("users");  //ref is my root location  
dataRef.set("I'm writing data")
.then(function(){
    alert("Data saved successfully.");
})
.catch(function(error){
    alert("Data could not be saved." + error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is not working at server side nodejs application running on windows 10.